# kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork Cache Miss

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform

If I never run the app before, when I set kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork on my query.cachePolicy property and run it, it will show UIAlertView with text "cache miss".

I try to build an app that use cache first then network.

What is the best way to get this effect without get UIAlertView showed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for the cache miss you should check for error code `120`. Just return (without presenting your `UIAlertView`) if you see that code.

If you want to show the error message only after the 1st time the error is seen, save a flag in `NSUserDefaults` that indicates the first cache miss has been encountered, and check for error code `120` and that the `NSUserDefaults` flag is not set. I'm not sure why you'd ever want to show a user that there has been a cache miss, especially if your policy is to go to the network after hitting the cache, because it's sort of irrelevant to them because the last (network) failure is the important one.

--- Edit ---

To disable the automatic UIAlertView that is shown when using the PFQueryTableViewController (or if you have enabled it) and an [error is encountered](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/Parse.html#//api/name/errorMessagesEnabled:) or the [user is offline](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/Parse.html#//api/name/offlineMessagesEnabled:), you can use the following code:

```
[Parse errorMessagesEnabled:NO];
[Parse offlineMessagesEnabled:NO];
```

Depending on which types of messages you want to show. I find it typically best to disable all of these, and handle errors within the application logic rather than showing alerts when any error appears, as things like cache misses, or no-data returned can result in errors being raised.

If you'd still like to use the parse alert view for errors, but not show cache miss errors, then what you can do is set your cache policy based on the cache contents. You can test a query to see if it has cached results with something like...

```
if ([myQuery hasCachedResults]) {
  myQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
} else {
  myQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
}
```

Then run your query.

Comment: I didn't present any UIAlertView. It's built in Parse Framework, and automatically showed when the cache is missing.
How do I prevent this UIAlertView for being appear?

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Ah, I see - it's _that_ alertview. Updated answer.

Comment: hasCachedResult seems to works well, I don't know why a big company like Parse didn't document this simple alert view behaviour. But thanks, it works and [Parse errorMessageEnabled:NO] nailed it.